# Getting the cabal version of a GHC compiled program?

Tags: haskell, cabal

If I compile an executable using GHC's `cabal build`, is there a way to get the version number as stated in the project `.cabal` file, from inside the `main` function?

For example, we can get the main program name using:

```
import System.Environment
main = do
    progName <- getProgName
    ...
```

Can we somehow write a similar function `getProgVer` to get the cabal-defined version number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
import Paths_PKGNAME

main = print version
```

Cabal will create a module `Paths_PKGNAME` (where `PKGNAME` is the name of your package) which contains among other things the version of the package. More info in the [users guide](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#accessing-data-files-from-package-code).

Comment: Thanks! Is there a specific field in the `.cabal` file that I can use for `PKGNAME`? I've tried values in `Name:`, and `executable:`.  But GHC says it cannot load the interface.

Comment: Its the `name:` field in your .cabal, with `-` replaced by `_`.

Comment: Very nice! One additional question: after adding `import Paths_PKGNAME`, `cabal build` can build successfully, but GHCi  would complain: `Failed to load interface for ‘Paths_...`. Is there a way to fix this as well?

Comment: You will need to use GHCi through 'cabal repl'.